# How to describe the span $M=\{(1,1,1),(0,0,2)\}$ in $R^{3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to describe the span $M=\{(1,1,1),(0,0,2)\}$ in $R^{3}$?

I found the answer in a book to be the plane $\xi_{1}=\xi_{2}$, but I am not sure how to get there?

Comment: What are $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$?

Comment: $$(1,1,1)-\frac{1}{2}(0,0,2)=(1,1,0).$$ This together with $(0,0,1)$ forms, by inspection, an orthogonal basis for the plane you have described. (@Arthur, $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3\}$ are the coordinates the vectors are written in terms of)

Comment: @Arthur, I am not sure. That is what it says in the book. The author doesn't give an explanation.

Comment: @MrDi: Then you might want to provide the *context* of your question. What book? What section?

Comment: @Jack, Kreyszig - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications section 2.1.

Comment: guys i can tell you right now, by construction $\xi_1$'s 'coordinate representation' is $(1,0,0)$, $\xi_2=(0,1,0),$ $\xi_3=(0,0,1)$. See my first comment. $${}$$ Also if this level of problem is confusing, you probably had better pursue some introductory linear algebra before you try to learn functional analysis.

Comment: @enthdegree, Is another method to take the cross product of the two vectors and set it to zero because that seems to give the same result?

Comment: There, $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are the first component and the second component of a vector in question, respectively. The property means vectors with equal first and second components, as you can readily see in the answers.

Comment: @MrDi:The answer in the back of the book interprets as "$\zeta_1=\zeta_2$" is isomorphic to the $xy-$plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}} (M) = \{a(1,1,1)+b(0,0,2) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{(a,a, a+2b) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}\} $$
Thus we obtain
$$\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{R}} (M) = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x = y\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Exercise**: 
$$
\text{span }M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x=y\}.\tag{1}
$$

**Hint**:

Write out the definition of $\text{span }M$ and show $\subset$, $\supset$ respectively for (1).

Comment: Is another method to take the cross product of the two vectors and set it to zero because that seems to give the same result?

Comment: Usually the dot product is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that you want to find out which equations of the form $ax+by+cz=0$ hold for vectors from $M$. (In the other words, you want to write $M$ as a set of solutions of a homogeneous linear system.)

From the fact that $(1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,2)$ are solutions you get the equations
\begin{align*}
a+b+c&=0\\
2c&=0
\end{align*}
Which gives you $c=0$ and $b=-a$.

So the equations which are valid for all vectors in $M$ are precisely the multiples of the equation
$$x-y=0.$$
You know that $\dim(M)=2$. (The given vectors are linearly independent.)

At the same time solutions of this equation form a 2-dimensional subspace (plane).

So you see that these two spaces are equal. (You have that $M$ is subspace of the solution space, but at the same time they have the same dimension.)

So you get $$M=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3; x-y=0\}.$$